# Cleaning up data with python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python would like a function that finds and deletes NaN from a dataset but doesn't delete the row or column that it is present with, only NaN,

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide a **specific** example of the code you've written so far, and any **specific** errors you may be encountering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas.fillna()` to replace **NaN**.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 2, np.nan, 0],
                       [3, 4, np.nan, 1],
                       [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5],
                       [np.nan, 3, 0, 4]],
                       columns=list('ABCD'))
df

     A    B   C  D
0  NaN  2.0 NaN  0
1  3.0  4.0 NaN  1
2  NaN  NaN NaN  5
3  NaN  3.0 0.0  4


df.fillna(0)


     A    B    C  D
0  0.0  2.0  0.0  0
1  3.0  4.0  0.0  1
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  5
3  0.0  3.0  0.0  4

#Or to replace with the mean
df.fillna(df.mean())
```

This will not delete the row. It will just replace the NaN values with 0.